# Perl sub loops could not reset iterate interal variable

Tags: perl, loops

When go into sub loops after jumped from it in next time, the iterate of sub loop should start from begin:

```
#!perl

use 5.014;

my %hash = ( "a" => 1, "b" => 2 , "c" => 3);
my $pos = 0;
POS: 
while ($pos < 4) {
    $pos++;
    while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
        say "key: $key value: $value";
        next POS;
    }
}
```

But the result is as follows:

```
$ perl bugs-loop.pl
key: c value: 3
key: a value: 1
key: b value: 2
```

How to get following result:

```
key: c value: 3
key: c value: 3
key: c value: 3
```

Comment: I would avoid using each() at all - it is too easy to get confused when a hash keeps internal state about how far through it you have iterated.

Comment: Exactly, don't use `each`, unless you are 100% sure you are iterating to the very end of a hash.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev ... and even then don't use `each`. :-)

Comment: @tobyink, what about perfomance issues?

Comment: Looping through `keys` and fetching values from the hash inside the loop is unlikely to be that much slower than `each` unless you're doing negligible work inside the loop. Even very experienced Perl programmers are saying that the potential for weird action at a distance with `each` means that it [should be avoided like the plague](http://blogs.perl.org/users/rurban/2014/04/do-not-use-each.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) resets the iterator. resets the internal iterator of the HASH or ARRAY (see `each`). In particular, calling `keys` in void context resets the iterator with no other overhead.

```
#!perl

use 5.014;

my %hash = ( "a" => 1, "b" => 2 , "c" => 3);
my $pos = 0;
POS: 
while ($pos < 4) {
    $pos++;
    while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
        say "key: $key value: $value";
        keys %hash;  # Reset iterator since we're bailing out.
        next POS;
    }
}
```